# Process Builder not able to download data into a file using cURL

Tags: java, curl, processbuilder

I am trying to use Process Builder to download data into a file:

```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "curl", 
            "--negotiate", 
            "-u" ,":" ,"-b", "~/cookiejar.txt", "-c", "~/cookiejar.txt", 
            "http:*****509-0500/mobile*****.snappy?op=open | snzip -d"
            );
    Process p;

    try
    {
        pb.redirectOutput(new File("~/testTest.txt"));
        p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();//added based on Earlybird's suggestion

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {   System.out.print("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here the file testTest.txt is created but nothing is appearing in the file (try block being successfull). The cURL command works fine on terminal.

Comment: curl does not understand pipe `|`, bash/shell does, so call bash and pass curl as argument to it

Comment: I am sorry could you elaborate on that?

Comment: you're using `|` in you command line, curl (program you're executing) does not know what to do with this pipe, it just ignores it

Comment: Similarly, `~` is only considered special by the shell.  There is no `~` directory.  Use `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "testTest.txt")` instead.